# IIS Web Farm not processing request

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-8, iis-8.5

I have setup a IIS web farm using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, IIS 8.5 with the following extensions: Web Farm Framework v1.1  External cache v1.0, URL Rewrite v2, ARR v3.

Ref: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/erezs_iis_blog/2013/11/27/installing-arr-manually-without-webpi/

The URL Rewrite rules contain a rule mapping of "*" generated automatically upon the creation of the IIS web farm.

I tried to access http://localhost/some_random_name and the request was processed by the local IIS instead of my IIS web farm and it returns HTTP 404.

I turned on FailedRequestTracing logging and there was no logs captured. I presume this is because the local IIS has processed the request as HTTP 404 instead of routing to the IIS web farm.

How do I troubleshoot/debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your url rewrite rules.
2. Create a website that handles all requests.
3. Make sure that website is accesible from the internet.
4. Create a URL Rewrite rule that rewrites all requests to web your farm like following.

You are done.
And here it is a sample URL Rewrite rule that already works on my machine.

```
<rule name="rule_name" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)?" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?YOUR_DOMAIN.com(:PORT)?$" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://WEB_FARM_NAME/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: I wanted to route the request to a group of servers instead of one

Comment: that's is the reason why I am using server farm

Comment: I thought so, so here it it is the last flow after this configuration; 1.) main website will capture and redirect traffic to your web farm. (in the same server) 2.) your web farm will distribute the traffic across your servers (which are in different machines afaik). the main purpose of the creating main website is just capturing the traffic and redirecting it to web farm.

Comment: it is not processing my request for some reasons

Comment: and I am trying to find a way to troubleshoot